# AngularJS sorting a list with nulls

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope object that has a list containing null values, I would like to sort this list in both directions but the null values must be always at the end. I can probably do this easily by splitting up the object into 2, one with nulls and one without then stick on the null list at the end. But is there a more efficient way to do this?

example:

```
[1,null,5,7,2,null]
```

sorted:

```
ASD: 1,2,5,7,null,null

DESC: 7,5,2,1,null,null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to sort the array, JavaScript has method `array.sort`. This takes a comparer function.

You can implement two of such functions one for ascending sorting and one for descending. Within these two functions you can treat nulls as you wish. See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

If you are using angularjs filter [orderby](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy) it too takes a comparer function, so a similar approach may work.

Comment: you cannot orderby without replacing the null values, it will break, as you cannot have duplicates in the item list, when using it in combination with ng-repeat.

Comment: Duplicate issue is with ng-repeat not orderby fiter that i know of. Why should orderby fail on duplicate values?

Comment: had to add the "in combination with ng-repeat" - in itself, using orderby is fine, but you will run into problems when displaying the items. however, i think this is the right answer for the case described.

Comment: You can have duplicates in an `ngRepeat` if you specify `track by $index` at the end of your repeater expression.

Comment: Problem is that the orderBy predicate is used to return the value to sort by and is not itself a comparator function i.e. the problem as described where `null` values are always at the bottom/end of the list isn't addressed. Here is a plunk showing the behaviour: http://embed.plnkr.co/GCpQGe/preview